# Visual Studio didn't generate pageName.xaml.cs

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I just created a new XAML page. The problem with this page is that the solution explorer doesn't show the pageName.xaml.cs(Doelen.xaml) file.
Does anyone know what is going on here?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you tryed to click F7 on your keyboard while your xaml is open? This should show the .cs-file.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you **definitely** add a `Page` to your solution? Right Click -> Add -> New Item -> Page. You can add a **XAML File** but this isn't the same thing.

Comment: I just did Right Click -> Add -> New Item -> XAML View. Nothing else, is there something wrong with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I just had to create a **Blank Page** except of **XAML View**.

Case closed, and thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the code behind file for the xaml is my guess. Was there any code in the cs or was it default? You could deleted the old xaml file and created a new xaml file. The new xaml file will have the code behind. Also, you could recreate the cs file by naming it to the same name as the xaml file with a cs extension added to it. Place it in the same directory as the xaml file. Visual Studio looks for it there.

Comment: It didn't create the xaml.cs at all.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is is that I create a .cs file with the name Doelen.xaml.cs?

Comment: Yes, use the other file that is working as a reference. You need to make sure the namespace is correct, etc.

Comment: You may need to close VS and open the project fresh when you get it situated. You could also try right-clicking on the project/solution and choose "reload".

Comment: Restarting didn't help, and creating that .cs class doesn't really make sense to me. Could you explain?

Comment: Just open the location of the files in Windows Explorer and you will see what MainPage.xaml.cs looks like. The actual file. Close Visual Studio so you don't get confused. Do all of this OUTSIDE visual studio. Make a copy of MainPage.xaml.cs and rename it. Then open the copy in notepad and make sure any references to MainPage are changed to Doelen. Then open VS.